# Why Ruby inject method cannot sum up string lengths without initial value?

Tags: ruby

Why the following code issues an error ?

```
['hello','stack','overflow'].inject{|memo,s|memo+s.length}

TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String
        from (irb):2:in `+'
        from (irb):2:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):2:in `each'
        from (irb):2:in `inject'
        from (irb):2
```

If the initial value is passed, it works OK:

```
['hello','stack','overflow'].inject(0){|memo,s|memo+s.length}
=> 18
```

Comment: I find the following syntax really nice `['hello','stack','overflow'].map(&:length).inject(&:+)` but it's certainly not relevant to your question.

Comment: @Jonas, yeah, that's cool. And since the reduction is a summatory we can write: ['hello','stack','overflow'].map(&:length).sum

Comment: Yes if you are using http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html you can. As far as I know, there's no `sum` in standard Ruby.

Comment: Where could I find documentation on `.map(&:length).inject(&:+)` syntax ?

Comment: @Misha: http://apidock.com/ruby/Symbol/to_proc explains the `&:method_name` part of the syntax. Enumerable's syntax will explain the `map` and `inject` part.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have the answer in [apidock](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject) :

> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then uses the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

That is, without an initial value, you're trying to do `'hello' + 'stack'.length`

Answer (score 6):

As the error message already tells you, the problem is that you have a `TypeError`. Just because Ruby is dynamically and implicitly typed doesn't mean that you don't have to think about types.

The type of `Enumerable#inject` without an explicit accumulator (this is usually called `reduce`) is something like

```
reduce :: [a] → (a → a → a) → a
```

or in a more Rubyish notation I just made up

```
Enumerable[A]#inject {|A, A| A } → A
```

You will notice that all the types are the same. The element type of the `Enumerable`, the two argument types of the block, the return type of the block and the return type of the overall method.

In your case, the types for the block just don't add up. The block gets passed two `String`s and it is supposed to return a `String`. But you call the `+` method on the first argument (which is a `String`) with an argument that is an `Integer`. But `String#+` doesn't take an `Integer` it only takes a `String` or more precisely something which can be *converted* to a `String`, i.e. something that responds to `#to_str`. That's why you get a `TypeError` for `String#+`.

The type of `Enumerable#inject` *with* an explicit accumulator (this is usually called `fold`) is something like

```
fold :: [b] → a → (a → b → a) → a
```

or

```
Enumerable[B]#inject(A) {|A, B| A } → A
```

Here you see that the accumulator can have a *different* type than the element type of the collection. Which is precisely what you need.

These two rules generally get you through all `Enumerable#inject`-related problems:

1. the type of the accumulator and the return type of the block must be the same
2. when not passing an explicit accumulator, the type of the accumulator is the same as the element type

Rule #1 will most often bite you when you do something like

```
acc[key] = value
```

in your block, because assignments evaluate to the assigned value, not the receiver of the assignment. You'll have to replace this with

```
acc.tap { acc[key] = value }
```

In your particular case, the two solutions have already been mentioned. Either use an explicit accumulator

```
ary.reduce(0){|acc, e| acc + e.length }
```

or convert to integers *first*

```
ary.map(&:length).reduce(:+)
```

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Thnaks fro teh speling fxies :-)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

Without the initial value, `inject` uses the first element in the collection as the initial value.

see [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003140).