# using inject to count elements in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, inject

I'm trying to count the occurrences of elements in an array and save it in a hash.  I'd like to use the inject function.  I have this code:

```
a = ["the","the","a", "it", "it", "it"]
a.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash,word| hash[word] += 1}
```

I don't understand why I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
    from (irb):47:in `[]'
    from (irb):47:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):47:in `each'
    from (irb):47:in `inject'
```

Also, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: When you don't know how to fix something, do debug printing. Print everything that happens. You'll likely have insights.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4314292/2988 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10576460/2988

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`inject` calls your block with two parameters, memo and current element. It then takes return value of the block and **replaces memo** with it. Your block returns integers. So, after first iteratation, your memo is not a hash anymore, it's an integer. And integers don't accept strings in their indexers.

Fix is easy, just return hash from the block.

```
a = ["the","the","a", "it", "it", "it"]
a.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash,word| hash[word] += 1; hash }
```

You may prefer `each_with_object` because it doesn't replace memo. Note that `each_with_object` accepts parameters in reverse (element first, memo second).

```
a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|word, hash| hash[word] += 1}
```

Comment: probably good answer, but for self learning I would ask you - *each_with_object accepts parameters in reverse (element first, memo second).* So how this reverse orders helps, which `inject` doesn't. Can I have more flavor on this?

Comment: It's not the order that helps. It's that `each_with_object` doesn't replace memo.

Comment: @RubyLovely the order has nothing to do with it, it's just how `each_with_object` works.

Comment: make sense now from the line *each_with_object doesn't replace memo*..forgot for a while..Thanks Buddy :)

Comment: @steenslag Intersting.. to know `inject` returns 1. But any doc for the same to see?

Comment: @RubyLovely `inject` does not return 1;  `hash[word] += 1`  does.